# 2d gaussian with matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, gaussian

I want to draw a gaussian in two dimension centered in the middle of the matrix with matlab. Right now I am doing with

```
for i = 1:size2
    for j = 1:size2
        gauss(i,j)=A*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*((i-round(size2/2))^2+(j-round(size2/2))^2)); %gaussiana
    end
end
```

but it can be extremely slow.

In matlab I have not found any function, what is the fastest way to do it? Is a mex file a valuable option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectorizing the gaussian computation using [meshgrid](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) is relatively trivial.

There is even an Octave implementation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function).

The implementation is:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size2, 1:size2);
G = A*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*((Y-size2/2).^2 + (X-size2/2).^2));
```

Note: I replaced the `round(size2/2)` with `size2/2` because the rounding is not part of the formula.

---

Trick for **converting 1D gaussian into 2D gaussian**:

For making the computation a little bit faster we can create 1D gaussian, and compute the 2D gaussian out of it:

```
x = 1:size2;
G1 = sqrt(A)*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*(x-size2/2).^2);  % Create 1D gaussian 
G2 = G1'*G1;  % Compute the 2D gaussian out of 1D gaussian.
```

---

Testing:

```
size2 = 101;
A = 10;
sigma = 50;
gauss = zeros(size2);

for y = 1:size2
    for x = 1:size2
        gauss(y,x)=A*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*((y-size2/2)^2+(x-size2/2)^2)); %gaussiana
    end
end

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size2, 1:size2);
G = A*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*((Y-size2/2).^2 + (X-size2/2).^2));

disp(['sum abs diff (G, gauss) = ' num2str(sum(abs(G(:) - gauss(:))))])

x = 1:size2;
G1 = sqrt(A)*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*(x-size2/2).^2);

G2 = G1'*G1;

disp(['sum abs diff (G1, G2) = ' num2str(sum(abs(G2(:) - G(:))))])
```

---

Output:
`sum abs diff (G, gauss) = 0`
`sum abs diff (G1, G2) = 7.1436e-12`

---

### Update:

According to Cris comment "meshgrid is no longer needed".
Since MATLAB r2016b we can use the following code:

```
X = 1:size2;
Y = X';
G = A*exp(-1/(sigma^2)*((Y-size2/2).^2 + (X-size2/2).^2));
```

The implementation relays on a feature named "implicit singleton expansion" or [Implicit Expansion](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/).

Comment: `meshgrid` is no longer needed since implicit singleton expansion. Just set `X = 1:size2; Y = X.';`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks', I never thought of using this feature for summing a column vector with a row vector.